# Why has my iPhone camera stopped focusing?

Tags: iphone, camera

My camera doesn't focus any more. Is that a known issue and is there a fix for this? If not, can I take it to be fixed? I had this phone for less than a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the phone is less than a year old, it will be covered by the default AppleCare warranty. I suggest contacting Apple, and they will probably just replace the phone outright.

Comment: So what happens if the phone is more than year old?  SOL?

Comment: @dev.e.loper: You need to read the terms of the agreement that came with your iPhone. The iPhone comes with 1 year standard, and within that year, you can extend the warranty. See http://www.apple.com/support/products/iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

Took it in Apple store. They fixed it. The motor that does the focusing was not working.  They fixed it for free.  Person who did the job told me that I don't need a warranty if this happens in the future they'll fix it for free because it takes very little time and no parts need to be replaced.